# Flask & Wtforms: 400 Bad Request - Submitting upload form

Tags: python, file-upload, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

Im trying to create a movie DB for a school project and I am getting a '400' after submitting the form.
The use of this form is to add Movies to your DB with a description, titel, year and picture(Url to DB) as of now.

routes.py:

```
@login_required
@app.route('/upMovie', methods=['GET'])
def movieup():
    return render_template('upload.html', MovieUploadForm=MovieUploadForm())


@login_required
@app.route('/upMovie', methods=['POST'])
def movieup_validate():
    upload_form = MovieUploadForm()
    if upload_form.validate_on_submit():
        if Movie.query.filter_by(title=upload_form.title.data).first() is not None:
            return 'Movie already exists.<a href="/upMovie">Back</a>'
        file = request.files['file']
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(upload_form.filename.file.filename)
            file_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
            upload_form.filename.file.save(file_path)
            movie = Movie(
                title=upload_form.title.data,
                info=upload_form.info.data,
                year=upload_form.year.data,
                filename=file_path,
                rating=5
            )

            db.session.add(movie)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect(url_for('uploaded_file', filename=filename))
        return 'Registration of movie successful.<br/><a href="/">Home</a>'
    else:
        upload_form.flash_form_errors()
        return render_template('errors.html')
```

forms.py:

```
class MovieUploadForm(StandardForm):
    title = StringField('Title', validators=[InputRequired(), length(1, 80)])
    info = TextAreaField('Info', validators=[length(1, 2000)])
    year = DateField('YYYY/MM/DD', format='%Y/%m/%d')
    filename = FileField('File URL')

    def flash_form_errors(self):
        for field, errors in self.errors.items():
            for error in errors:
                flash("<strong>Error in field: %s</strong> - %s" % (getattr(self, field).label.text, error))
```

funtions.py

```
def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1] in app.config['ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I experimentent around for a while and found a working solution.
The changes I made in routes.py

```
if upload_form.validate_on_submit():
    if upload_form.filename.data.filename is not "":
        filename = secure_filename(upload_form.filename.data.filename)
        file_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
        # file_path = "imdb/static/pic/" + filename
        upload_form.filename.data.save(file_path)

    movie = Movie(
        title=upload_form.title.data,
        info=upload_form.info.data,
        year=upload_form.year.data,
        filename=file_path if upload_form.filename.data else None,
        rating=5
    )
    db.session.add(movie)
    db.session.commit()
    return 'Registration of movie successful.<br/><a href="/">Home</a>'
```

As we are getting our date from our wtforms, we don't need to `file = request.files['file']` as the object we are getting is empty.

in forms.py

```
 class MovieUploadForm(StandardForm):
title = StringField('Title', validators=[InputRequired(), length(1, 80)])
info = TextAreaField('Info', validators=[length(1, 2000)])
year = DateField('YYYY/MM/DD', format='%Y/%m/%d')
filename = FileField('File URL', validators=[FileAllowed(['jpg', 'png', 'jpeg'], 'Images only!')])

def validate(self):
    v = Form.validate(self)
    if not v:
        return False

    if Movie.query.filter_by(title=self.title.data).first() is not None:
        self.title.errors.append("Movie already exists!")
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

I changed them accordingly, with allowed file endings and also added a Validation for duplicates.

With this code everything seems to work just fine.